# A question on the parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f:[-2,5] \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)= x^2-2mx+m+2$ The smallest value that the function can take is $-10$. Find the sum of the values that $m$ can take.

Comment: The smallest value occurs at the vertex of the parabola. Do you know how to find the vertex?

Comment: You do know you can write text _outside_ the dollar signs, right? You don't have to have a backslash before every space, and it looks better.

Comment: @rogerl I tried but it didn't work out.

Comment: @Hatm00 keep in mind the minimum value can also occur at boundary, [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bsolve+-10+%3D+(x)%5E2+-+2m*(x)+%2B+m+%2B+2,+%7Bx,+-2,+5,7%7D%5D)

Comment: You're right but also I found the values that you found and vertex value. As I said it didn't give the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest value of $ax^2+bx+c$ (when $a>0$) is taken at $x$ halfway between the roots, which is
$$
x=-\frac{b}{2a}=m
$$
(For $a<0$, that abscissa gives the maximum value.)

However, your problem is a bit more complicated, because you bound the function over $[-2,5]$. Then the minimum value can be at $m$ (if it is in this range), at $-2$ or at $5$.

Now you have $f(-2)=5m+6$ and $f(5)=-9m+27$. Also
$$
f(m)=m^2-2m^2+m+2=-m^2+m+2
$$

- If $-2<m<5$, the minimum value is taken at $m$
- if $m\le-2$, the minimum is taken at …
- if $m\ge5$, the minimum is taken at …

We have $f(m)=-10$ if and only if $m^2-m-12=0$, that is $m=4$ or $m=-3$.

We have $f(-2)=-10$ if and only if $m=-16/5<-2$.

We have $f(5)=-10$ if and only if $m=37/9$.

Two of these values have to be discarded.

Comment: When the root exists, if the first claim aims to be general (since we are in a precalculus context). Or are you assuming that we can refer also to the compelx roots in that context?

Comment: Hey smallest value can also occur at boundary right ?

Comment: But it's a delimited function. It can be equal f(-2) or f(5). Is my thought wrong?

Comment: @gimusi Shifting the parabola up or down doesn't change the point where the minimum is taken, only the minimum value. The halfway point doesn't change with such a translation.

Comment: @Hatm00 I added further hints

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum or minimum of a parabola occurs at its vertex at $(h, k)$.

$$h = \frac{-b}{2a}$$

$$k = c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

Since you have $a = 1 > 0$, then a minimum exists.

$$k = -10 \iff c-\frac{b^2}{4a} = -10 \iff (m+2)-\frac{4m^2}{4} = -10$$

$$\frac{4m+8-4m^2}{4} = -10 \iff -4m^2+4m+8 = -40$$

$$-4m^2+4m+48 = 0 \iff m^2-m-12 = 0 \implies (m-4)(m+3) = 0$$

This yields $m = 4$ and $m = -3$, but only the former is applicable given the limited domain.

Comment: But we don't know is vertex in definition range.

Comment: @Hatm00 I’ve edited the answer. (I misread the question.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. If we add root with the boundary values we can reach the result.

Comment: It would be good if the downvoter clarifies if the answer is missing anything.